# Copy text from a disabled JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Is it possible to allow a user to copy text from within a disabled JTextField?  At the moment if I have a text field that is disabled, the user is unable to select the text to copy and paste into another app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the text field non editable, then you can still use the mouse to select text.

You can also change the font color to make it look disabled.

Comment: JTextComponent has a getDisabledTextColor() method you can use.

Answer (score 3):

Camickr's suggestions are the right on, but alternatively you could add a right click menu option with a copy action.